# Attaching list of tuples together

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of tuples which looks like this in Haskell:

```
([],[[]],[])
```

And I want to perform some operations on these lists and return all possible changes of state onto them. I want to return a list of this tuple and I am not quite sure how to bind them together. When I tried cons or ++ I get some errors.

```
([],[[]],[]):([],[[]],[])
([],[[]],[])++([],[[]],[])

<interactive>:81:1:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’
            with actual type ‘([t0], [t1], [t2])’
Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:81:1)
In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘([], [], [])’
In the expression: ([], [], []) ++ ([], [], [])
In an equation for ‘it’: it = ([], [], []) ++ ([], [], [])
```

Comment: well you cannot do `:` or `++` on tuples (those are for lists) - and you have no *list of tuples* you have a **tuple of lists** - can you please post an example of what you want to do (what is the expected outcome here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your main problem here is that you have an *tuple of lists*  instead of a *list of tuples* as you claimed - so of course neither `:` nor `++` will work.

Maybe you want to use those operations component-wise, which can be done by something like:

```
map3 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, a, a) -> (b, b, b) -> (c, c, c)
map3 op (xs,ys,zs) (xs',ys',zs') = (xs `op` xs',ys `op` ys',zs `op` zs')
```

using this you get:

```
λ> map3 (++) ([],[[]],[]) ([],[[]],[])
([],[[],[]],[])
λ> map3 (:) ([],[[]],[]) ([],[[]],[])
([[]],[[[]],[]],[[]])
```

if this is not what you expected / wanted then please add an example on what you want

Comment: I think the OP wants this to work when lists are non empty, which is more tricky to achieve since they no longer share the same type `a`. Indeed, in the most general case I think it's impossible without e.g. intersection types `map2 :: (a1 -> b1 -> c1 && a2 -> b2 -> c2) -> (a1, a2) -> (b1, b2) -> (c1, c2)` which of course we do not have in Haskell. We need to settle with something simpler, but it's not completely clear what that should be.

Comment: it just seems so strange to only use `[]` and I thought maybe it's some attempt at naturals using empty-sets or something

Comment: as soon as OP gives some details I'll probably delete the answer but I want to wait if this is ok with you

Comment: I would not delete this -- it could help the OP to formulate the question more precisely. After all, this does answer the question as stated, even if probably not as intended. (If SO were a genie, I'd recommend "be careful about what you wish for..." ;-) )

Comment: @user3237465 In the most general case they are not e.g. `mapPair succ (3::Int, 'a')`. What you propose it's probably more than enough for most practical uses, though.

Comment: @chi, I meant "enough in this case". With intersection types it's even possible to express self-application, which is clearly not possible with just higher rank ones. But we can define [another](http://ideone.com/sxGepU) ad hoc `mapPair`.